# Exibir resultados separados por vírgulas com MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
administrador  | regiao
bruno          | 2,3,4
pedro          | 1
jose           | 5,7
```

Tenho uma tabela administrador e uma tabela região, onde 1 administrador pode administrar uma região ou várias. Quero fazer uma consulta que me traga o nome das regiões que cada administrador é responsavel separando por vírgulas. Ex:

```
administrador  | regiao
bruno          | São Paulo, Belo Horizonte, Sorocaba
pedro          | Boituva
jose           | Rio de Janeiro, Resende
```

Como fazer essa consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois entender melhor o problema eis meus pensamentos e possíveis soluções.

#### Solução 1:

A melhor ideia seria reestruturar as tabelas com *foreign keys*. N-1 caso as áreas só possam ter apenas **um** administrador. N-N caso uma área possa ter vários administradores e cada administrador possa administrar várias áreas.

Se for escolhida a opção N-1, a resposta do @ricardo-pontual é exatamente o que tu precisa. Desde que a tabela `regions` tenha uma chave estrangeira para a tabela `administrators`.

Resposta do @ricardo-pontual para referência:

```
SELECT 
    a.nomeAdm as nome,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.nomeREg SEPARATOR ", ") as regiao
FROM regiao r
INNER JOIN administrador a ON r.idAdm = a.idAdm
GROUP BY r.idAdm;
```

Caso N-N seja a necessidade, mantenho a resposta anterior que é ter um tabela pivô com chaves estrangeiras para `regions` e `administrators`.

```
SELECT
    a.nome as administrador,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.nome SEPARATOR ", ") as regioes
FROM administradores as a
INNER JOIN adm_regioes AS ar ON ar.adm_id = a.id
INNER JOIN regioes AS r ON ar.regiao_id = r.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

#### Solução 2:

Se não for possível reestruturar as tabelas, é possível fazer um join usando [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) para que o SGBD reconheça o campo `regions` e consiga fazer a referência à tabela `regions`.

Um exemplo seria:

```
SELECT
    a.nome as nome,
    a.regions as regions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.nome SEPARATOR ', ') as regions_concat
FROM administrators as a
INNER JOIN regions as r
    ON a.regions REGEXP CONCAT("[[:<:]]", r.id, "[[:>:]]")
GROUP BY a.id;
```

**Resultado**:

```
+-------+---------+----------------------+
| nome  | regions |    regions_concat    |
+-------+---------+----------------------+
| Pedro |       1 | Sao paulo            |
| João  |     2,3 | Campinas, Manaus     |
| José  |     4,5 | Campo Grande, Santos |
+-------+---------+----------------------+
```

O `INNER JOIN` seria feito aplicando a [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) na coluna onde os símbolos `[[:<:]]` e `[[:>:]]` são os *word boundaries* (equivalente ao `\b` em outras engines de REGEXP).

Dessa maneira teu problema é resolvido, porém deve-se salientar que não é o ideal e também nem um pouco performático.

[Veja em funcionamento no DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWueJXpRfF1TzGtvJwDQba/3)

*PS: É preciso testar se funciona normalmente com números de dois ou mais dígitos também*.

---

Estas são as opções que vejo sem precisar tratar a nível de aplicação. Espero que ajude.

Comment: acho que se rodar no mesmo select, vai duplicar o nome do administrador...

Comment: Vou atualizar com o DISTINCT então.

Comment: Não é um N-N, só tenho duas tabelas, a de Administrador e a de Região...a tabela de administrador guarda os ids da região separados por virgulas, como descrito na pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa @DaywisonFerreiraLeal... vou melhor a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Fiz um fiddle para validar, aproveitando a ideia do `group_concat` da resposta do @fernandosavio:

```
select a.nomeAdm as nome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.nomeREg SEPARATOR ", ") as regiao
  from regiao r
 inner join administrador a on r.idAdm = a.idAdm
 group by r.idAdm, a.nomeAdm
```

Aqui o fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06be20/8

Answer (score 0):

```
select admin.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.name SEPARATOR ", ") as regiao
  from regions r
 inner join administrator admin on r.id = admin.regions
 group by r.id, admin.name order by admin.id desc
```

O resultado da Query acima foi:

```
name | regiao
pedro| sao paulo
joao | manaus
jose | campo grande
```

Quando na verdade deveria ser:

```
name | regiao
pedro| sao paulo
joao | manaus, campinas
jose | campo grande, santos
```

A query não está fazendo as concatenações, só esta considerando a primeira região.
Lembrando que as tabelas estão assim :

```
Regions
id | name
1  | Sao paulo
2  | Manaus
3  | Campinas
4  | Campo Grande
5  | Santos

Administrator
id | name | regions
1  | pedro| 1
2  | joao | 2,3
3  | jose | 4,5
```

Comment: Na tua query tu está agrupando por região e por administrador, quando aparentemente tu quer que agrupe apenas por administrador.
Se tu tirar o `r.id,` do `GROUP BY` tua query vai fazer mais sentido, logicamente falando.
O realmente problema e quebrar o campo `regions` dentro do `SELECT` pra usar no `WHERE`

Comment: Já removi o **r.id** do GROUP BY mas ele continua não concatenando as regiões de cada administrador..

Comment: Suponho que o campo `administrator.regions` é `VARCHAR`. Se for o caso, o MySQL está convertendo o campo para inteiro e por isso não enxerga as outras regiões. Pois quando ele converte "1,2,3" pra INTEGER o valor convertido é `1`.

Comment: A resposta do @ricardo-pontual seria a forma correta de fazer essa relação 1-N.

Comment: @fernandosavio o campo regions é varchar mesmo, acabei de ver aqui na tabela.

Comment: Alguma solução?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta. Se não tiver como alterar a estrutura do campo vai ter que usar REGEXP no JOIN mesmo.

Comment: Meu problema foi resolvido usando REGEXP, como mencionado na sua soluçāo